# IntelliJ inspects "Unhandled Exception" & multiple other error but Project compiles successfully Java SDK 1.6

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-6

Platform: IntelliJ Community Edition 2020.3
Project/Moudle SDK: jdk1.6.0_45
Project language level: 6 - @Override in interfaces
Module Dependencies: jdk1.6.0_45
OS: Windows 10

Moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ for this old source code base & I can see lots of errors but when I build Project, it compiles properly. How can I get rid of these errors, I cannot go update all classes to add throw/catch/method params comments, etc. Also, this is not maven based project.

```
Errors: Unhandled exception, Cannot resolve symbol, etc
```

What I have done till now, reading through other's suggestions:

- `File > Invalidate Caches and restart the IDE 3-4 times`
- `File >  Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler >`
  `Changed Project` `& Target Bytecode Version to 6`

Some of the files from `.idea dir`

**misc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_6" project-jdk-name="1.6" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK" />
</project>
```

**mySourceCode.iml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_6">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/out/production/mySourceCode" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/out/test/mySourceCode" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/out" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="1.6" jdkType="JavaSDK" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Ext_Jars" level="application" />
  </component>
</module>
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/mySourceCode.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/mySourceCode.iml" />
    </modules>
  </component>
</project>
```

**compiler.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="CompilerConfiguration">
    <excludeFromCompile>
      <file url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/java/test/test.java" />
    </excludeFromCompile>
    <bytecodeTargetLevel target="6">
      <module name="mySourceCode" target="6" />
    </bytecodeTargetLevel>
  </component>
</project>
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide simplified project example for investigation?

Comment: @y.bedrov so this is the project structure, assume there is just one class that has an exception type that is not handled rest all are. It shows error but compiles successfully

Comment: Is it reproducible with new project?